# connection between azure private flexible postgres and aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-lambda, azure-postgresql, aws-site-to-site

need to connect azure flexible private postgresql and aws lambda  ,so I used site to site VPN connection is up both sides,but while lambda function trying to connect with dB server private dns it couldn't resolve name, while trying with private ip it getting login rejected,if anybody know how to resolve it please let me know.

- Created customer gateways and gave Azure gateway pubic IP
- Created virtual private gateway to customer gateways.
- Now created site to site VPN  and  selected vitual private gateway  and attached virtual private gateway and customer gateway ID and gave subnet id of azure database private subnet
- Now in azure created local network gateway and gave Virtual Private Gateway outside ip address   which provided by vpn downloaded configuration and gave addressing space as network of aws vpc
- Now gone to gateway and create one connection and attach gateway and attach the local gateway that created in previous step and gave shared key which is from downloaded configuration
- added route to aws lambda private subnet

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/), and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure) for immediate help. Thanks!